# Unable to get google signin authenticated with backend srever with futter android app even after sending right Id_token

Tags: php, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

**Just a map to store post request body**

```
var rqstParameters = {
  'email': '',
  'loginMethod': '',
  'name': '',
  'token': ''
};
```

**Google Login triggered on this button pressed**

```
return RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              authService.googleSignIn().then((user) {
                user.getIdToken(refresh: true).then((usrTokenId) {
                  rqstParameters['email'] = user.email;
                  rqstParameters['loginMethod'] = '4';
                  rqstParameters['name'] = user.displayName;
                  // printWrapped(usrTokenId.token);
                  rqstParameters['token'] = usrTokenId.token;
                }).whenComplete(() {
                  fetchPost().then((response) {
                    var body = response.body;
                    print(body);
                  });
                });
              });
            },
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Text(
              'Signin with GOOGLE',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          );
```

**Request Looks like this--->**

```
Future<http.Response> fetchPost() async {
  // print(rqstParameters);

  final response = await http.post(
    'https://this/is/the_server.in/dashboard/login.php',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
    body: rqstParameters,
  );
  print(response.statusCode);

  return response;
}
```

**This is Authentication Logic used for Google Signin**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AuthService {
  FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Shared State for Widgets
  Observable<FirebaseUser> user; // firebase
  PublishSubject loading = PublishSubject();

  // constructor
  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async {
    loading.add(true);

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    ); 


    final AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = result.user;

    // Done
    loading.add(false); 
    print("signed in as " + user.displayName );
    return user;
  }

  void signOut() {
    _auth.signOut();
  }


final AuthService authService = AuthService();
```

**This is the response body i am getting back from server-->**

```
{"email":"example@question.com","name":"Users Display Name","token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI1MDgxMWNkYzYwOWQ5MGY5ODE1MTE5MWIyYmM5YmQwY2ViOWMwMDQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.NBuuCCtFMjBQghBjEDajSyEqbBYF567yN3u7fk1gCx8nzrVAYyVLc1f7zQoId0dsjfjahPnnMoTpU3mAdrL-PyWgJIwxI4WjKNyhhAy9XXgWZa8gUb5APAPYbcomPxiuThrE8-Bfkr-vdSTkviwRLzk2XKCNi-wtXGYrikQ34Rj5FzmRsPzGa6dLICyB-qyhbAOwQ-jhjsdhfuCMgUISseyl-ol5Ua_RnE7KHwdjNxTvVdnax_cT42uY88cpGGQc3JksdjhfrKAvTe19dzu092kMVnG91euFMBUQw2Nu6a6cdq7k4vz-egZd1IMIwkrmSQiRQihG3ODEOhPPuuo2lEsO7iHMldF3c4D_oA","payload":false,"error":"payload not verified"}
```

**server uses this PHP code to verify client**

```
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]); 
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
   //login Successful
} else {
  // payload not verified
  // login Failed

}
```

Why payload is not getting verified when the tokens are all sent correctly and proper flow is maintained...please help.. :(